# How do I remove the automatic breakpoints/coefficients from the segmented package?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have been running analysis on data that involves breakpoints and I'm using the `segmented` package. When I run my analysis, I get the following output:

```
fit <- lm(XBRrate~Gap, data = batstraining2)
summary(fit)
segmented.fit <- segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~Gap, fixed.psi = 100)
summary(segmented.fit)
```

```
> summary(segmented.fit)

    ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = fit, seg.Z = ~Gap, fixed.psi = 100)

Estimated Break-Point(s):
          Est. St.Err
psi1.Gap   74  3.761

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.0157829  0.0118917   1.327   0.1847    
Gap           0.0036064  0.0001935  18.635   <2e-16 ***
U1.Gap       -0.0012212  0.0002588  -4.719       NA    
U1.fixed.Gap -0.0017419  0.0007509  -2.320   0.0205 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03699 on 1046 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.6456,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.6443 

Boot restarting based on 10 samples. Last fit:
Convergence attained in 1 iterations (rel. change 2.627e-07)
```

The problem is it includes the U1.Gap in its final model, which is easiest to see in the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXUzf.png).

I need to not have this auto breakpoint included. In the community, we understand there are breakpoints at fixed intervals, which is why I want to use those fixed breakpoints. but since it includes that auto breakpoint at 74 everything is wrong after 74.

I have tried using npsi as well, and while the breakpoints won't have the exact same issue, sometimes it will put breakpoints at very odd places that make no sense to actually have breakpoints in context.

I also tried using the `strucchange` package but it didn't seem to give results that made sense. The examples I found online were formatted for date data, and this is not date related. I'm not 100% sure if this is the issue, but if that's a better option I would need someone to show me a different way to use it, most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to fit a segmented regression without estimating breakpoints (i.e., with breakpoints that are known a priori), you could just estimated a piecewise linear regression using `lm()`.  Specifically, you would need to include the variable of interest and a piecewise linear basis function.  Here's what the basis function would look like:

```r
pwl <- function(x, k)ifelse(x >= k, x-k, 0)
```

where `x` is the variable and `k` is the knot location.  You could use it in the regression model as follows:

```r
data(mtcars)
library(car)
library(ggeffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + pwl(hp, 180), data=mtcars)
summary(mod)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + pwl(hp, 180), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -5.0587 -2.1073 -0.6383  1.5470  8.1293 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  34.81289    1.94632  17.887  < 2e-16 ***
#> hp           -0.11099    0.01504  -7.382 3.92e-08 ***
#> pwl(hp, 180)  0.10415    0.02996   3.476  0.00162 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.301 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7194, Adjusted R-squared:    0.7 
#> F-statistic: 37.17 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 9.947e-09
```

Note that the coefficient on `hp` gives the slope of the relationship before the knot and the coefficient on `hp` plus the coefficient on `pwl(hp, 180)` gives the slope after the knot.  You could use the `linearHypothesis()` function from the `car` package to test whether the slope after the knot is different from zero.

```r
linearHypothesis(mod, "hp + pwl(hp, 180) = 0")
#> Linear hypothesis test
#> 
#> Hypothesis:
#> hp  + pwl(hp, 180) = 0
#> 
#> Model 1: restricted model
#> Model 2: mpg ~ hp + pwl(hp, 180)
#> 
#>   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
#> 1     30 317.31                           
#> 2     29 315.99  1    1.3211 0.1212 0.7302
```

You could even use the `ggpredict()` function from the `ggeffects` package to plot what the effect looks like:

```r
p <- ggpredict(mod, term="hp [all]")
plot(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's probably a better way of doing what I have done! I'm not a great coder so I tend to hard code things. I just created two separate models. and the r squareds are 0.7073 and 0.7783. Using this method I got an r squared of 0.8664, which is pretty close to the segmented r squared of 0.8669. The only thing I'd have to figure out is how to do two separate knots with this method, but it may not be something I have to do in practice anyway.

Also sorry for the long delay - i got busy with school and my work is done on video game data, which had a new release in late March.

Comment: @IRockThs you can actually just add another `pwl()` term with another knot location and it should all work out.